How to convert set-theory expression into FOL formula mechanically?
I am looking for a systematic way to convert set-theory expressions into FOL (with the only non-logical symbol $\in$) formulas. Take $x \Cup \{x\} \in S$ for example, which FOL formula does it correspond to?

$z \in S \wedge \forall y \, (y \in z \iff (y \in x \vee y=x))$
$\exists z \, (z \in S \wedge \forall y \, (y \in z \iff (y \in x \vee y=x))).$


@MauroALLEGRANZA The Mathias paper is quite misleading. If you do it intelligently, you can eliminate defined symbols with only a polynomial blowup in size: https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/772062.772068 .
